# Why do most area calculations result in 0?

Tags: qgis

I would like to autocalculate area (acres) for a shapefile that is in UTM zone 16 CRS.

I have tried the "Vector|Geometry Tools|Add/export geometry columns" and also the field calculator.  The first gives me a warning saying

```
currently QGIS doesn't allow simultaneous access from threads to the same data source.
Make sure your layer's tables are closed. Continue?
```

When I click `YES`, it creates two new columns   `AREA`  &  `PERIMETER`.

- The AREA column is mostly 0's with a few values such as 2e-06 and so on.
- The PERIMETER column gives mostly values along the lines of .003526 and so on.

**Questions:**

- What is the warning it is giving me and why are the values so
  sporadic?
- Also when I use the field calculator tool, it seems to give
  me values close to what the field area should be but when I click
  SAVE EDITS all the values turn to 0's. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like QGIS didn't pick up the layer's projection. If you right-click the layer > properties > General tab, in the field to the left of "Specify CRS".. is it really showing your expected coordinate system?

Comment: Make sure you use a CRS in meter + try to add the columns manually using the field calculator and $area as command

Comment: could be wrong as i am unfamiliar with the CRS and most of the above....but using the information tool in the CRS which i work usually bring up a "derived" tab which when expanded (providing it is a polygon) tell you the area in hectares.

Comment: The comments to this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66113/how-to-measure-area-of-polygons-generated-from-gps-data-in-qgis may lead you to the solution.